# IE7 & IE8 error with mootools+json request Access is denied

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-7, mootools

In mootools I use the `Request.JSON(options).get();` to send a request to the server.
Options is:

```
{'onSuccess':function(){alert(1)},'url':'https://192.168.12.219/reports/get/favorite/details/?report_id=7'}
```

the url I am in is: https://192.168.12.219/reports/container/
So I do not see any issues with cross domain (this code works perfectly in FF/Chrome any other normal browser).

The error I get is:

> Access is denied

I monitor the Apache error and access log - I see nothing there, so it seems to me this has stopped at the client and not some funky error code the Apache returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah it says it in the subject line

Comment: @etbal: oops! Can you access this url when typed in the address bar ?

Comment: no - if you see the IP you see it is inside a private network. I gave the url so you can see there is no ssl/cross domain issues

Comment: I meant: can you access this url directly, not by Ajax, using IE ?

Comment: @Fabien Ménager - yes I can access this url directly

Comment: There is a good reason to put the error message as a tag. Please do not remove it from there.

Answer (score 1):

In normal browsers, they find out you are still in the same domain even if I use complete URL, so I can use

> 'url':'https://192.168.12.219/reports/ge.......

But, in IE7 it assumes you are doing cross domain stuff if you enter full url, so, if I put relative path (even from root, it works just fine )

> /reports/ge.......

Some one was lazy at MS

Comment: Also, if you need x-domain requests use Request.JSONP